# For loop for turning pages and appending data from the table

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to open a link, then create a .csv sheet and then go to page 2 and append the data below the data of first page and so on and once the last page is reached it should stop navigating.

```
 i=c(seq(1,250, 25))
 j=c(seq(26,250,25))
 n=c(seq(1,15,1)) #n = no. of pages 15 is the max. 

for (p in n){

for (k in j){

  for (l in i){
   tryCatch({  
  ara <- paste0("some website with multiple pages.......pageNumber=",p,"&startRecord=",l,"&endRecord=",k)

     mybrowser$navigate(ara)

   doc <- htmlParse(mybrowser$getPageSource()[[1]])
    Sys.sleep(1)

               docrf <<- readHTMLTable(doc)

               ab2<<-docrf$'SearchResultsTable'

               Sys.sleep(5)

               ab2%>%write_csv("C:/Users/Kisf/Documents/newlist2.csv",append=TRUE) #this is not appending data


    },error=function(e){})
    }
      }
   }
```

the link navigates in a infinite loop instead of stopping at page no. 9 which is the last page.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I am not sure the superassignment operator, <<- is needed in your case, as you don't need to overwrite a global `docf` or `ab2`.

Comment: that is not helping... the for loop is infinite, it doesn't stop now the data is getting appended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three nested `for` loops which is parsing each page 90 times.  The result isn't an infinite loop, but might take considerable time to finish iterating.  Below is probably closer to what you're looking for (assuming that 25 records can be parsed per page).

```
n <- seq_len(11) #number of pages to parse
step <- 25 #number of records to retrieve per page

for (p in n){
  aa <- paste0("http://.......pageNumber=", p, "&startRecord=", (p - 1) * step + 1, "&endRecord=", p * step)
  #other code as desired
}
```

Comment: when I run the code it is not going to the next page and I'm getting an error 
    Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "write_csv"
I've installed readr package. is there any alternative to write_csv for appending data.

Comment: From the loop what I understand is that 
"ageNumber=",p,"&startRecord=",l,"&endRecord=",k)" in this partp which is the page number and k which is the end Record remain constant until all the input in 'l' that is startRecord is over. Then k is replaced with second input from the sequence the whole loop goes again and so on.

Whereas I want the n, l, k to changed simultaneously.

Comment: The library needs to be loaded after installation to access the functions:  `library(readr)`

Comment: The current answer will change all three values simultaneously.  If this isn't changing in the sequence that is desired, update the question to include example values as the comment above isn't very clear.

Comment: @manotheshart, thanks the script is perfect it is changing all the three values. But I want to do something like "trycatch() " so that the for loop stops when there is error (no table to read from the table), currently it keeps on running 11 iterations. (The number of pages are dynamic may be more or less than 11)
 write.table(ab, "cfgtt.csv",na = "",row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE,append = TRUE,sep = ",")
This is parsing the columns names everytime it takes reads the table, is it doable to take the column name only once in the entire loop?

Comment: It might be easier to check the website response and then conditionally exit the loop; take a look at `?break`

Comment: change the `write.table` argument to `col.names = (p == n[1])` which will evaluate `TRUE` for the first iteration and then `FALSE` after that